# Collect data from visible rows only applying manual filter

Tags: excel, vba

I created the macro below (my first time macro ever) to automatically generate PDFs in bulk, creating one per row populating a Word template with the corresponding fields. Now, I need to filter the data to generate PDFs only for the remaining visible rows, but cant figure out what lines of the code to modify to make this happen. I have read about the .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) but I have no idea where to use it nor if it is even the way to go. I would greatly appreciate some help. Thanks!

```
Sub PrintPrivacyPolicyDoc_EN()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim objWord As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim datos(0 To 1, 0 To 9) As String

Set a = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
nom = ActiveWorkbook.Name
pto = InStr(nom, ".")
nomarch = Left(nom, pto - 1)
wArch = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & a.Range("B3").Text & ".dotx"

uf = a.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
objWord.Visible = True
uf = a.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
objWord.Visible = True
For j = 5 To uf
Set wdDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(wArch)
nomfic = nomarch & "_" & a.Cells(j, "A") & "_" & a.Range("C3").Text
rutainf = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "PrivacyPolicy PDFs" & "\" & nomfic & ".pdf"

'Variables to find and text to substitute"
datos(0, 0) = "[Company_Name]"
datos(1, 0) = a.Cells(j, "B")
datos(0, 1) = "[Vat_Number]"
datos(1, 1) = a.Cells(j, "C")
datos(0, 2) = "[URL_Stay]"
datos(1, 2) = a.Cells(j, "D")
datos(0, 3) = "[Update_Date]"
datos(1, 3) = a.Cells(j, "E")

For I = 0 To UBound(datos, 2)
textobuscar = datos(0, I)
objWord.Selection.Move 6, -1
objWord.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=textobuscar
While objWord.Selection.Find.Found = True
objWord.Selection.Text = datos(1, I) 'texto a reemplazar
objWord.Selection.Move 6, -1
objWord.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=textobuscar
Wend
Next I

'Search for the file and delete it before saving the newest verion

    If Dir(rutaInf) <> "" Then
        Kill rutaInf
    End If
    'Save file with the designated name
    wdDoc.SaveAs Filename:=rutaInf, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
    'Close Word template without saving changes
    wdDoc.Close savechanges:=False

    MsgBox ("PDF files were successfully generated"), vbInformation, "NOTIFICATION"
    wdDoc.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI it's a good habit to always use indenting in your code so it's easier to read (for us *and* you...) A few blank lines between sections would also help.  Finally On Error Resume Next should really be used as little as absolutely necessary - it can hide problem with your code and lead to difficult-to-locate bugs.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! I will have it in mind for the next time :)

Comment: Thanks @Naresh! I read the string you linked in your comment. The problem is that I am a newby at this and I have a lot of problems understanding the bit that  works for me in other peoples  code... I would very much appreciate if you could walk me through what and where should I fix my code... Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub PrintPrivacyPolicyDoc_EN()

    Dim objWord As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim nomArch As String, uf As Long, wArch As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, j As Long, nomFic As String, rutaInf As String

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    nomArch = Split(ws.Name, ".")(0)
    wArch = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Range("B3").Text & ".dotx"

    uf = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
    objWord.Visible = True

    For j = 5 To uf
        If Not ws.Rows(j).Hidden Then 'visible rows only
            
            Set wdDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(wArch)
            nomFic = nomArch & "_" & ws.Cells(j, "A") & "_" & ws.Range("C3").Text
            rutaInf = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PrivacyPolicy PDFs\" & nomFic & ".pdf"
        
            ReplaceAll wdDoc, "[Company_Name]", ws.Cells(j, "B")
            ReplaceAll wdDoc, "[Vat_Number]", ws.Cells(j, "C")
            ReplaceAll wdDoc, "[URL_Stay]", ws.Cells(j, "D")
            ReplaceAll wdDoc, "[Update_Date]", ws.Cells(j, "E")
            
            If Dir(rutaInf) <> "" Then Kill rutaInf
            'Save file with the designated name
            wdDoc.SaveAs Filename:=rutaInf, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
            wdDoc.Close savechanges:=False
        
        End If 'row not hidden
    Next j

    objWord.Quit 'close Word

End Sub

'Replace all instances of txtFind with txtReplace in doc
Sub ReplaceAll(doc As Word.Document, txtFind As String, txtReplace As String)
    With doc.Range.Find
      .Text = txtFind
      .Replacement.Text = txtReplace
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank for your answer! I ran the code you suggest but it generates the PDF of the line right after the visible one. It skips the visible one and generates de PDF of the next one, although it is hidden... What do you thinks is going on?

Comment: sorry for being such a pain... It seems to work but now the last bit of code (that I failed to paste at the begining) that is supposed to generate and save the final PDF doesnt work... Could you help me with it?? I edited my original post to include it just as I currently have it. With this final fix I am positive if will work perfectly. Thank you so much!!

Comment: What does it do instead of working?  Do you get an error message, if Yes what is the message and on which line?

Comment: What you have looks OK to me - edited it in above...